# × Unhandled Rejection (Error): invalid fragment object (argument="value", value=

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, unhandled, ethers.js, react-app-rewired

I am new to Smart Contracts.
I am unable to read a smart contract from Binance test network. I keep getting an Unhandled Rejection every time I attempt to read my smart contract using ethers.js.

**Error**

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): invalid fragment object (argument="value", value=[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"string","name":"_name","type":"string"},{"internalType":"string","name":"_sr_number","type":"string"},{"internalType":"string","name":"_branch","type":"string"},{"internalType":"string","name":"_date","type":"string"},{"internalType":"string","name":"_grade","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"branch","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"date","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"getName","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"grade","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"sr_number","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.0.13)

**My code**

```
 const first_div = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let abi = [
      [
        {
          "inputs": [
            {
              "internalType": "address",
              "name": "_owner",
              "type": "address"
            },
            {
              "internalType": "string",
              "name": "_name",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "internalType": "string",
              "name": "_sr_number",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "internalType": "string",
              "name": "_branch",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "internalType": "string",
              "name": "_date",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "internalType": "string",
              "name": "_grade",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ],
          "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
          "type": "constructor"
        },
        {
          "inputs": [],
          "name": "branch",
          "outputs": [
            {
              "internalType": "string",
              "name": "",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ],
          "stateMutability": "view",
          "type": "function"
        },
        {
          "inputs": [],
          "name": "date",
          "outputs": [
            {
              "internalType": "string",
              "name": "",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ],
          "stateMutability": "view",
          "type": "function"
        },
        {
          "inputs": [],
          "name": "getName",
          "outputs": [
            {
              "internalType": "string",
              "name": "",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ],
          "stateMutability": "view",
          "type": "function"
        },
        {
          "inputs": [],
          "name": "grade",
          "outputs": [
            {
              "internalType": "string",
              "name": "",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ],
          "stateMutability": "view",
          "type": "function"
        },
        {
          "inputs": [],
          "name": "name",
          "outputs": [
            {
              "internalType": "string",
              "name": "",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ],
          "stateMutability": "view",
          "type": "function"
        },
        {
          "inputs": [],
          "name": "owner",
          "outputs": [
            {
              "internalType": "address",
              "name": "",
              "type": "address"
            }
          ],
          "stateMutability": "view",
          "type": "function"
        },
        {
          "inputs": [],
          "name": "sr_number",
          "outputs": [
            {
              "internalType": "string",
              "name": "",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ],
          "stateMutability": "view",
          "type": "function"
        }
      ]
  ];
    let provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider();
    let contractAddress = "0x60aD9FCD26092de54CDF3Ff83900a5B5a52887Ab";
    let contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider);
    let currentValue = await contract.getName();
    alert(currentValue);
  };
```

***My solidity file***

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract FactoryContract {
    
    address public owner = msg.sender;
    
    address [] public createdContracts;



    event ContractCreated(address contractAddress);
    
    function createContract(string memory _name, string memory _sr_number, string memory _branch, string memory _date, string memory _grade) public {
        
         address newContract = address(new Contract(msg.sender, _name, _sr_number, _branch,  _date, _grade));
         
         
         emit ContractCreated(newContract);
         
         createdContracts.push(newContract);
        
    }
    
    function getDeployedContracts() public view returns (address[] memory)
    {
     return createdContracts;
    }

    function getOwner() public view returns (address)
    {
     return msg.sender;
    }

    
}

contract  Contract  {
    address public owner;
    string public name;
    string public sr_number;
    string public branch;
    string public date; 
    string public grade;
    
    modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
        }
    
       constructor  (address _owner, string  memory _name, string memory _sr_number, string memory _branch, string memory _date, string memory _grade) {
        owner = _owner;
        name = _name;
        sr_number=_sr_number;
        branch = _branch;
        date = _date;
        grade = _grade;

        }

        
    function getName() public view returns (string memory)
    {
     return name;
    }

}
```

Where am I going wrong? I have deployed the contracts using a factory contract. I've used the ABI of the contract and not the ABI of the factory contract.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra set of square brackets when you're declaring your `abi` variable. There should only be one set of square brackets surrounding the ABI.